# jQuery crash bootstrap navi on my website

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hello guys i got problem with my website (work in progress)
Here is a problem:

Website includes 2 versions of jQuery - in my theme folder and wp include. 
When both versions run all scripts works, but bootstrap mobile navi get crashed.

When i comment my jQ in functions.php navi works, but other scripts be crashed.

Here is website adres: http://blueform.damiansonek.eu/

Any ideas to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using noConflict since you are using two versions of jQuery at the same time? This could cause problems is you are not.

Comment: I resolve problem overwriting my jQuery version to this WP included.